# date range for six monthly in pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, group-by, time-series, data-analysis

So, this is my data frame.

```
PatientNumber           QT         Answer   Answerdate  DiagnosisDate 
1        1          transferring     No      2017-03-03 2018-05-03     
2        1          preparing food   No      2017-03-03 2018-05-03     
3        1          medications      Yes     2017-03-03 2018-05-03     
4        2          transferring     No      2011-05-10 2012-05-04       
5        2          preparing food   No      2011-05-10 2012-05-04     
6        2          medications      No      2011-05-10 2012-05-04     
7        2          transferring     Yes     2011-15-03  2012-05-04     
8        2          preparing food   Yes     2011-15-03  2012-05-04     
9        2          medications      No      2011-15-03  2012-05-04     
10       2          transferring     Yes     2010-15-12 2012-05-04     
11       2          preparing food   No      2010-15-12 2012-05-04     
12       2          medications      No      2010-15-12 2012-05-04     
13       2          transferring     Yes     2009-10-10 2012-05-04     
14       2          preparing food   No      2009-10-10 2012-05-04     
15       2          medications      No      2009-10-10 2012-05-04     
16       3          medications      No      2008-10-10 2010-07-04
```

I just found one link related to my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48454189/pandas-date-range-for-six-monthly-values) that it did not get any correct answer.

**some explanations:**
 for each patientNumber, diagnosisDate is unique.and Answer Date is several time they have filled a questionary.

but what I  want to do:?

my goal is to go back from `DiagnosisDate` `every six month`, and mark that on to a column `as the first 6 month record`. in the column we should save which six month is that(the first six month, the second, the third,...).

for example for this dataframe, `DiagnosisDate` for `PatientNumber=1` is `2018-05-03` so it should go back from that time `6 month`. `the first 6 month` is `2017-27-11` as the biggest AnswerDate do not fall under that date, it wont be marked as `first six month`. 
if the first `answerdate` falls under this date, it will be marked as `first 6 month`.

so here `PatientNumber=1` got `3` in the column `6month`, because when we get back from `diagnosisdate` `6 month` back, the `answerdate` falls under that `6 month` there time later.
so the output of this dataframe will be:

```
PatientNumber           QT         Answer   Answerdate  DiagnosisDate  6month
1        1          transferring     No      2017-03-03 2018-05-03     3
2        1          preparing food   No      2017-03-03 2018-05-03     3
3        1          medications      Yes     2017-03-03 2018-05-03     3
4        2          transferring     No      2011-05-10 2012-05-04     1 
5        2          preparing food   No      2011-05-10 2012-05-04     1
6        2          medications      No      2011-05-10 2012-05-04     1
7        2          transferring     Yes     2011-15-04  2012-05-04    2
8        2          preparing food   Yes     2011-15-04  2012-05-04    2
9        2          medications      No      2011-15-04  2012-05-04    2
10       2          transferring     Yes     2010-15-12 2012-05-04     3
11       2          preparing food   No      2010-15-12 2012-05-04     3
12       2          medications      No      2010-15-12 2012-05-04     3
13       2          transferring     Yes     2009-10-10 2012-05-04     5
14       2          preparing food   No      2009-10-10 2012-05-04     5
15       2          medications      No      2009-10-10 2012-05-04     5
16       3          medications      No      2008-10-10 2010-07-04     4
```

For PatientNumber =2, it will start from `DiagnosisDate =2012-05-04` and go back 6 month.it will be `2011-11-04`.

I applied this:

```
data['6month'] = pd.date_range(end=data['diagnosisdate'],periods=2, freq='6M',closed='left')
```

firstly it just care about month, so calculate approximately not exactly, 
and I could not find a way to mention the number of 6 month, like the thing I mention in the above dataframe(in the column 6 month I meantion 1 2, ... instead of the date.

Therefore according to the data, we may see in the column `6month` the numbers from `1...10`(considering 5 years before diagnosis)

Long story. hope someone can take time :).

Also I need to keep the whole column on the result as it is.

Comment: Hi Saria please share with us your `df.to_dict()` so we can reproduce.

Comment: Do you mean to say that `6month` should be `diagnosis_date` - 6 months?

Comment: @ user32185 thanks for asking, but what do you mean, as I have shared a sample of dataframe, which I thought it will be enough. please let me know what other thing is required?

Comment: @ifly6 thanks for asking. my goal is to analyses the patients answer each 6 month. so from diagnosisdate back, I have to consider their answers for each 6 month. later I will do some analysis on each 6 month. please let me know which part is still ambiguous . thanks

Comment: @ifly6 I added some clarification, and explained the number in the output for patientnumber1. hope it makes it more clear :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not exactely what you want, but a work around giving good enough results. I think you can do by calculating the time difference between column DiagnosisDate and Answerdate, and divide by `pd.np.timedelta64(6, 'M')` (to change the frequency to 6 months). Then you need the `ceil` function to get the integer above, such as:

```
data['6month'] = (pd.np.ceil((data['DiagnosisDate']-pd.Timedelta(days=1)-data['Answerdate'])
                                             /pd.np.timedelta64(6, 'M')).astype(int))
```

for ignoring negative columns:

```
data = data[(data['6month'] >= 0)]
```

With your sample, it gives:

```
    PatientNumber            QT Answer Answerdate DiagnosisDate  6month
1               1  transferring     No 2017-03-03    2018-03-05       3
2               1     preparing     No 2017-03-03    2018-03-05       3
3               1   medications    Yes 2017-03-03    2018-03-05       3
4               2  transferring     No 2011-10-05    2012-04-05       1
5               2     preparing     No 2011-10-05    2012-04-05       1
6               2   medications     No 2011-10-05    2012-04-05       1
7               2  transferring    Yes 2011-03-15    2012-04-05       3
8               2     preparing    Yes 2011-03-15    2012-04-05       3
9               2   medications     No 2011-03-15    2012-04-05       3
10              2  transferring    Yes 2010-12-15    2012-04-05       3
11              2     preparing     No 2010-12-15    2012-04-05       3
12              2   medications     No 2010-12-15    2012-04-05       3
13              2  transferring    Yes 2009-10-10    2012-04-05       5
14              2     preparing     No 2009-10-10    2012-04-05       5
15              2   medications     No 2009-10-10    2012-04-05       5
16              3   medications     No 2008-10-10    2010-04-07       3
```

Also, I would not use `pd.date_range` as it seems not to act like you want, but I might be wrong.

EDIT: to remove the case where DiagnosisDate is before Answerdate, once you have created your column 6months, just do `data = data[data['6months'] > 0]` as the value would be negative or zero in this case

Comment: Many thank for your time, well why did not use the functions of the pandas which is good for working with time? actually it can not help me, the numbers in 6month is important , it helps me to analyse the answers of the patient every six month before getting sick. having that approximately later produce wrong result. I believe we can do with time series function in pandas like the thing I shared above. anyway thanks for putting time please let me know if you ad any idea

Comment: @sariaGoudarzi I had trouble copying your data so I edit my results. I understand why you don't want wrong number, but I believe this solution gives good results. If you want to use `pd.date_range`, I think you should look at doing something like `data.apply(lambda row: len(pd.date_range(start=row['Answerdate'], end=row['DiagnosisDate'], freq='6M',closed='left')),1)` but, at least on your sample, you get the same results :)

Comment: T many thanks for following, it seems I copied day and month wrongly please check the datafarme in the question some minutes later. maybe your way with the updated dataframe give the desired output

Comment: now the order in the date in the dataframe is year/day/month, with this can you please apply your code on the updated dataframe?

Comment: @sariaGoudarzi yes it seems days and months are mixed up, thanks each country to have their own way to write date ^^.

Comment: @sariaGoudarzi can you confirm for the first row: diagnosis is the 5th of March 2018 and answer is the 3rd of March 2017. If yes, are you sure you want 2 in the columns 6months and not 3 as it's just above 1 year so it should be 3 times 6 months? if yes, I don't understand the problem.

Comment: I am so sorrrry :| yiu are right. I had a very busy today and at the same time I had to work on this, thats why I made some mistake in the desired output. I am updating. thanks for pointig that

Comment: @sariaGoudarzi no problem, I also think your last row is wrong (sorry I did not say earlier) I update slightly my method (substract a day), and it should fit what you need. I know it's not with `pd.date_range` but not sure how to use it

Comment: Seems working :D, perfect . many thanks for taking the time. may I ask you just update your answer in which not consider the negative ones? it happens when the patient will be diagnosed first and then come to hospitals. so answerdate is bigger than diagnose date . I am not interested on those. again thank you.

Comment: also can you please give explanations about this pd.Timedelta(days=1) ? I did not get what it is doing. then I will accept your perfect answer as desired one. many thankss :)

Comment: @sariaGoudarzi pd.Timedelta(days=1) is a day. In order to consider, as you wanted, 1 for the first row of patient number 2, you need to say that the period of 6 month you look back start the day before, otherwise, the same day 6 months before is not comprised in this period. It's a thing about intervals and bounds (hope it's more clear....)

Comment: I did not see your update for negative, now I can not delete that part I just added. feel free  to update it and back to original one :)