# Pandas - date range with monthly rollover, weekmask and list of holidays

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I was looking for similar problem but I could not have find an answer for my issue. I try to generate date range in Pandas with monthly or quarterly rollover in respect to a weekmask and a list of holidays. So far I managed to make a range but with daily frequency. Is there any way I could make this dates rolling monthly or quarterly (not daily)?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
weekmask_pd = 'Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri'
holidays_pd = ['2019-11-15', '2019-12-13']
bday_pd = pd.offsets.CustomBusinessDay(holidays=holidays_pd, weekmask=weekmask_pd)
start_date = pd.Timestamp('2019-11-13')
end_date = pd.Timestamp('2020-11-13')
dts = pd.bdate_range(start_date, end_date, freq=(bday_pd))
```

The result of the following code is as follow:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2019-11-13', '2019-11-14', '2019-11-18', '2019-11-19',
               '2019-11-20', '2019-11-21', '2019-11-22', '2019-11-25',
               '2019-11-26', '2019-11-27',
               ...
               '2020-11-02', '2020-11-03', '2020-11-04', '2020-11-05',
               '2020-11-06', '2020-11-09', '2020-11-10', '2020-11-11',
               '2020-11-12', '2020-11-13'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', length=261, freq='C')
```

What I would like to receive is:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2019-11-13', '2019-12-16', '2020-01-13', '2020-02-13',
               '2020-03-13', '2020-04-13', '2020-05-13', '2020-06-15',
               '2020-07-13', '2020-08-13',
               ...
```

Any help please?

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a nice solution provided by @MaxU at [Pandas date_range for six-monthly values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48454189/pandas-date-range-for-six-monthly-values)
However it does not behave as expected because it skips start_date in 1) and 2) solution while it returns an error in 3) solution.

1)

```
dts2 = pd.bdate_range(start_date, end_date, freq='CBMS', weekmask=weekmask_pd, 
      holidays=holidays_pd) + pd.offsets.Day(start_date.day-1)
```

2)

```
dts3 = pd.bdate_range(start_date, end_date, freq='CBMS', weekmask=weekmask_pd,
      holidays=holidays_pd)+ datetime.timedelta(days=start_date.day-1)
```

1) and 2) return the same date range:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2019-12-14', '2020-01-13', '2020-02-15', '2020-03-14',
               '2020-04-13', '2020-05-13', '2020-06-13', '2020-07-13',
               '2020-08-15', '2020-09-13', '2020-10-13', '2020-11-14'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

3)

```
dts3 = pd.bdate_range(start_date, end_date, freq='CBMS-{}'.format(start_date.day), weekmask=weekmask_pd, holidays=holidays_pd)
```

returns:

```
ValueError: invalid custom frequency string: CBMS-13
```

I would appreciate any comments or hint how to make this date range include start_date and how to make quarterly, semiannually or annually rollovers as I do not see any custom frequency string for these.

Comment: @ MaxU - Hi Max, could you please take a look at my question and answer. I have tried to introduce your solution however it does not behave same way as in your example. I would appreciate any hint.